# Rewriting the page path from /my-drupal-project/docroot/user/login to /project/user/login using Drupal 8/Thunder?

Tags: .htaccess

I'm helping someone write some ReWriteRules for their Drupal project, but the expected behaviour for:

`ReWriteRule ^my-project/(.*)$ /my-drupal-project/docroot/$1`

isn't happening - there seem to be multiple .htaccess files in the project. Adding the rule to the .htaccess and another in `docroot` takes us to a 404 error page.

I'm gonna assume someone has had to do something similiar in the past, but I can't see anything in my searches that solves the issue.

Any help or direction appreciated.

Comment: You are searching in the wrong places. Leave Drupal's .htaccess alone and publish the public Drupal folder like you would publish any other folder. How to do this depends on the web server you use and is not a Drupal question.

Comment: Fair enough - I did think the docroot should be the 'docroot' but I don't think they have access to the Apache conf files.

Since this is deemed off-topic, shall I just delete the question? Serves no other purpose to me now.

Answer (score 1):

on the root of your Drupal project find `.htaccess` file, then search for `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]` and after that add the following line and save the file.

```
 ReWriteRule ^my-project/(.*)$ /my-drupal-project/docroot/$1 [R=301,L]
```

make sure clear the drupal cache and check it on a **New incognito window** first. ( sometimes browsers cache the redirects )